# How to pass props through Link?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass `chart` props through `Link` react-router.
so I tried to pass it through `route` but that is not what I expected bc each data has its own array number so I think I should pass it through Link but it doesn't work as I expected.
so here is the code :

DataSettingPage

```js
const DataSettingPage = ({ changeLayout, **chart** //this one  }) => {
  const layout = [
    <DataSide id="first" key="1233" onClick={chartItself}>
      <SettingMenu show={show[0]} ***chart={chart[0]}*** // to here />
      {chart[0]}
    </DataSide>,
    <DataSide id="second" key="1234" onClick={chartItself}>
      <SettingMenu show={show[1]} chart={chart[1]} />
      {chart[1]}
    </DataSide>,
    <DataSide id="third" key="1235" onClick={chartItself}>
      <SettingMenu show={show[2]} chart={chart[2]} />
      {chart[2]}
    </DataSide>, ....] 
    
    return (
    <Main>
      {changeLayout === "1+3 " && (
        <OneThree>{layout.slice(0, 4)}</OneThree>
      )}
      {changeLayout === "2+2 " && <TwoTwo>{layout.slice(0, 4)}</TwoTwo>}
      {changeLayout === "3+1 " && (
        <ThreeOne>{layout.slice(0, 4)}</ThreeOne>
      )}  
      </Main>
  );
};

export default DataSettingPage;
const Main = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
`;
```

SettingMenu

```js
const SettingMenu = ({ show, chart }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Setting show={show}>
        <Box>
          <Link to={{ pathname: `/realtime`, state: { chart: chart } }}>
            <TimerIcon style={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
            <p>realtime</p>
          </Link>

          <Link to="/csvFile">
            <InsertDriveFileIcon style={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
            <p>csv</p>
          </Link>
        </Box>
      </Setting>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values that are passed to the state attribute can be retrieved via location object provided by react-router. So for your case, the solution would be,

DataSettingPage

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom"

const DataSettingPage = ({ changeLayout }) => {
    { chart } = useLocation().state // Added this line
    

  const layout = [
    <DataSide id="first" key="1233" onClick={chartItself}>
      <SettingMenu show={show[0]} ***chart={chart[0]}*** // to here />
      {chart[0]}
    </DataSide>,
    <DataSide id="second" key="1234" onClick={chartItself}>
      <SettingMenu show={show[1]} chart={chart[1]} />
      {chart[1]}
    </DataSide>,
    <DataSide id="third" key="1235" onClick={chartItself}>
      <SettingMenu show={show[2]} chart={chart[2]} />
      {chart[2]}
    </DataSide>, ....] 
    
    return (
    <Main>
      {changeLayout === "1+3 " && (
        <OneThree>{layout.slice(0, 4)}</OneThree>
      )}
      {changeLayout === "2+2 " && <TwoTwo>{layout.slice(0, 4)}</TwoTwo>}
      {changeLayout === "3+1 " && (
        <ThreeOne>{layout.slice(0, 4)}</ThreeOne>
      )}  
      </Main>
  );
};

export default DataSettingPage;
const Main = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
`;
```

SettingMenu

```
const SettingMenu = ({ show, chart }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Setting show={show}>
        <Box>
          <Link to={{ pathname: `/realtime`, state: { chart: chart } }}>
            <TimerIcon style={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
            <p>realtime</p>
          </Link>

          <Link to="/csvFile">
            <InsertDriveFileIcon style={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
            <p>csv</p>
          </Link>
        </Box>
      </Setting>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank u so much but , I got an `unexpected token` error on ` { chart } = useLocation().state` here

Comment: It would help if you could share a sandbox with your code, otherwise consider posting the full error log.